# jquery - button just user the top

Tags: jquery

I have delete button. by clicking on it i run ajax code that delete the data from the DB.

when i click on the button the user screen jump to the top of the page.
How can i prevent that from happened?

I want the user to stay at the same place while the box been deleted...

HTML

```
<article class="row fadeSec" id="60">
    <a href="#" class="delBtn" data-type="itin-comment" data-alert="true"><i class="fa fa-trash pull-right"></i></a>
</article>

<article class="row fadeSec" id="61">
    <a href="#" class="delBtn" data-type="itin-comment" data-alert="true"><i class="fa fa-trash pull-right"></i></a>
</article>
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).on("click", ".delBtn", function(){

    var element = $(this);
    var deleteID = element.closest('.fadeSec').attr("id");
    var type = element.attr("data-type");
    var alertMsg = element.attr("data-alert");

    if (alertDeleteComment(deleteID))
    {
        var info = 'deleteID=' + deleteID + "&type=" + type;          
    //  alert(info);
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'ajax/ajax_delete_id.php',
          data: info,
          async: false,
          success: function (data) {
              if (data != "false") {
                  element.closest('.fadeSec').animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
              }
          }
          });
    }
```

});

Comment: `$(document).on("click", ".delBtn", function(e){ e.preventDefault(); } ` will prevent the default action of the anchor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should prevent the default behaviour for this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".delBtn", function(e){
e.preventDefault(); // <---- THIS IS THE PREVENTION

    var element = $(this);
    var deleteID = element.closest('.fadeSec').attr("id");
    var type = element.attr("data-type");
    var alertMsg = element.attr("data-alert");

    if (alertDeleteComment(deleteID))
    {
        var info = 'deleteID=' + deleteID + "&type=" + type;          
    //  alert(info);
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: 'ajax/ajax_delete_id.php',
          data: info,
          async: false,
          success: function (data) {
              if (data != "false") {
                  element.closest('.fadeSec').animate({ opacity: "hide" }, "slow");
              }
          }
          });
    }
```